# Can I put Cancel so far away to the left?

Tags: loading, cancel

I enclosed a sketch of my recent design. This is part of a screen of a game-related application which is currently searching for game updates.

I am wondering if it's ok to put the "Cancel" button where I put it - I did so to make it harder for users to automatically click on it without reading and to increase distance form the "Play" button at the same time.

[image]

Comment: Just wondering: does pressing Play not cancel the checking for updates?

Comment: No, I changed it and it's now disabled. It becomes active when the checking for updates is cancelled :)

Answer (score 4):

I read "Cancel" before "Checking for updates", which is wrong.
Place the Cancel option centered below the "Checking for updates" Option or next to it to make it more clear, i think you still have enough space to not make users accidentally click on that.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is OK to "hide" the cancle button somewhat.

You could do this by displaying the cancle button not as a button but as a textbutton. Something like this.
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too, and proposed it to the client, we'll see :)

Answer (score 2):

You can potentially flip the entire box so that 'Play' is on the left and 'cancel' is on the right. This is based on the premise that you have a LTR reading audience.

Also, is the purpose of this box to get users to wait for updates before playing?

If so, might be worth considering removing the play button until the check for updates has been completed - this way the user is forced to check for updates before the click the 'Play' button. If the updates are essential for smooth game play then this is also a reason why.

Comment: Yeah I know, which is why I disabled "Play" so the users have to wait for the updates. Although it becomes active again when users cancel checking for updates due to connection problems (Playing is possible without internet connection)

Comment: What about making the button dynamic?  First it would be 'Cancel' when checking for updates. If Cancelled or updated, the button changes to Play.

Comment: Well, I would like to maintain consistency and while dynamic button would work on some screens (or actions), it wouldn't on others, because I have a screen there where a player can either choose to update the game to the latest version or play the previous version, so I still have to display two buttons at the same time. Which is why I decided to stay with the convention of enabling/disabling the "Play" button and adding a second one according to situation.